# Count down two numbers alternatively

Tags: python

I am learning python and I am doing [these exercises](https://projecteuler.net/problems), specifically [this one](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) on palindrome product.

I have two numbers which I want to decrease by 1 but in an alternating fashion:

```
999, 999
998, 999
998, 998
997, 998
997, 997
...
```

I have solved it with 4 if statements, but I think this is a bit sloppy. Is there a better way? Bellow is the code:

```
palN1 = 999
palN2 = 999


def palin(palN1, palN2):
pal = palN1 * palN2
    while str(pal)[::-1] != str(pal):
        if palN1%2 == 0 and palN2%2 == 0:
            palN1 += -1
            pal = palN1 * palN2
            elif palN1%2 != 0 and palN2%2 == 0:
            palN2 += -1
            pal = palN1 * palN2        
        elif palN1%2 != 0 and palN2%2 != 0:
            palN1 += -1
            pal = palN1 * palN2
        elif palN1%2 == 0 and palN2%2 != 0:
            palN2 += -1
            pal = palN1 * palN2  
    print [palN1, palN2]
    print str(pal)

if __name__=="__main__":
    palin(palN1, palN2)
```

BTW the results I get for the exercise are [836,836] and it's product 698896.
This is my first post, sorry if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
def solve(*args):
    args = list(args)
    le = len(args)
    c = cycle(range(le))
    print ("{} "*le).format(*args)
    for _ in xrange( le*args[0] ):
        i = next(c)
        args[i] -= 1;
        print ("{} "*le).format(*args)
...         
>>> solve(999,999)
999 999 
998 999 
998 998 
997 998 
997 997 
996 997 
...
...
>>> solve(999,999,999)
999 999 999 
998 999 999 
998 998 999 
998 998 998 
997 998 998 
997 997 998 
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtract current step number integer-divided by 2 from both numbers, and additionally subtract 1 from the first number if the step number is odd:

```
>>> p = [999,999]
>>> for i in range(9):
...     print( [p[0]-(i//2)-(i&1), p[1]-(i//2)] )
```

Results:

```
[999, 999]
[998, 999]
[998, 998]
[997, 998]
[997, 997]
[996, 997]
[996, 996]
[995, 996]
[995, 995]
```

Comment: Another similar way: `p[0] - 1 - i // 2, p[0] - (i + 1) // 2`. +1 for thinking about integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Create two counters with [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and alternate between them in a generator function:

```
from itertools import count

def count_two_alternate(start):
    count1, count2 = count(start, -1), count(start, -1)
    count_val1, count_val2 = next(count1), next(count2)
    while count_val1 or count_val2:
        yield count_val1, count_val2
        count_val1 = next(count1)
        yield count_val1, count_val2
        count_val2 = next(count2)
    yield count_val1, count_val2
```

or, version with variable number of counters:

```
from itertools import cycle, counter

def count_alternate(start, counters=2):
    counts = [count(start, -1) for _ in xrange(counters)]
    values = [next(c) for c in counts]
    indices = cycle(range(counters))
    while any(values):
        yield tuple(values)
        index = next(indices)
        values[index] = next(counts[index])
    yield tuple(values)
```

Short demo:

```
>>> for c1, c2 in count_two_alternate(5):
...     print c1, c2
... 
5 5
4 5
4 4
3 4
3 3
2 3
2 2
1 2
1 1
0 1
0 0
```

or for the variable number version:

```
>>> for counts in count_alternate(5, 5):
...     print ' '.join(map(str, counts))
... 
5 5 5 5 5
4 5 5 5 5
4 4 5 5 5
4 4 4 5 5
4 4 4 4 5
4 4 4 4 4
3 4 4 4 4
3 3 4 4 4
3 3 3 4 4
3 3 3 3 4
3 3 3 3 3
2 3 3 3 3
2 2 3 3 3
2 2 2 3 3
2 2 2 2 3
2 2 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2
1 1 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can decrease the largest item:

```
palN1 = 999
palN2 = 999
while palN1 and palN2:
    if palN1 > palN2:
        palN1 -= 1
    else:
        palN2 -= 1
```

Comment: I like your answer. It's for newbies like me :D. Alternatively I also did it with an alternating boolean pattern. Can't I post code in the comments?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. I can't vote positive until I have 15 reputation :(